# How to display images when selecting data from a UIPickerview in Apple's iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, image, view, sdk, picker

I have a multicomponent picker with two separate wheels showing relative information. I want to display an image depending on which component is selected. For example: if "AA" is selected from both wheels, image AA will be displayed. If the right wheel is changed to "B", image AB will be displayed.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PickerController: UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *titleStrings;
    UIPickerView *picker;
    UIImage *imageView;
}
@end

@implementation PickerController

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        titleStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", NULL];
        picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100)];
        picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:picker];
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"empty.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
        [picker release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [titleStrings release];
    [super dealloc];
}

/* UIPickerViewDataSource */

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 2;
}

/* UIPickerViewDelegate */

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [titleStrings objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *first = [titleStrings objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    NSString *second = [titleStrings objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]; 
    NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", first, second];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [imageName release];
    [imageView sizeToFit];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to coding and I'm struggling! Could you look at my code and show me what I need to do. Also, how do I upload code like you have above? Thanks

Comment: If you are not able to copy and paste code to the editor, you have yet a lot to learn. I bet if you just copy into Xcode with the default main.m file, you should get a reasonable result.